# Is it true that 'Putzfrau' is used for males as well?

Tags: gender

A friend of mine, who's spent some time in Germany, told me today that in German, the noun *Putzfrau* is often used for male cleaners as well. This goes beyond all logic, since I found the word *Putzmann* in the dictionary.

Is it true that *Putzfrau* is (or at least used to be) used for male cleaners as well? If so, was it perhaps a mocking/pejorative term?

Comment: So is this where the English (derogatory) term of "putz" comes from?  Basically calling someone a janitor?

Comment: A woman can become a _Müllmann_ or be a _Fachmann_ in some subject, too.

Comment: Ich, als Hausfrau, kann Dir sagen, ...

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 No, "putz" is from Yiddish.

Comment: Never heard it in that context, but it's possible. It would be similar to "nurse" in English. Since it's a profession with inherent stereotypes about it often you need to make it clear that a nurse is male, whenever that's the case. I think these days Putzkraft or Reinigungskraft is more often used at least in the places I came in touch with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Putzmann* exists but is rarely used, indeed.

If you talk about cleaners in general you will (almost always) use *Putzfrau* unregarded if the person could be (or even is) a man.

> Nach der Party bestellte ich eine Putzfrau.

Sometimes when I talk about a male cleaner I want to say instinctively *Putzfrau* and while articulating I hesitate because I recognize my mistake. Then I often try to stress *Putzfrau* in an ironical or amusing way.

If you know that the cleaner you're talking about is male and you pay attention on not being derogatory you typically replace *Putzfrau* with  *Putzkraft* or *Putzhilfe* rather than *Putzmann*.

> Unsere Putzkraft hat heute mal wieder die Fenster vergessen.

Answer (score 7):

"Putzmann" actually is an uncommon word, I do not remember anyone actaully using it, besides to make some jokes.

So if you are looking for a word that includes male cleaners I would use "Reinigungspersonal" for cleaning personnel or "Reinigungsfachkraft" which is a jobtitle and is geneder neutral as well.

To refer to you question: Yes and no: If you refer to cleaning personell in spoken language you just talk about "Putzfrau" never about "Putzmann". However if you explicitly want to address the gender of a male cleaner without using the suggestions above you may use "Putzmann".

Answer (score 6):

By definition when referring to a *"[Putzfrau](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Putzfrau)"* we talk about a female person (this is also the image that comes to mind).

I never heard anybody refer to a male cleaner as *"Putzfrau"*, not even in a colloquial or familiar setting.

There are other, better suited words for that like e.g.

> - Reinigungskraft
> - Putzhilfe
> - Raumpfleger

Despite its existence [*"Putzmann"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Putzmann) is only rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about `Putzfrauen`, female or male, at least in my social circle, people might often use the pejorative short form `Putze`. Nevertheless it still has the female sounding touch to it. (But I think this is based solely on the expectation to have a female Putze and not a male Putzfrau).

Comment: Maybe because it is a derivation from *Putzfrau*. The article is *die Putze* and not *der Putze* (*der Putzmann*).

Comment: @Em1: True, but that counts for die Putzhilfe and die Putzfachkraft, too ;)

Comment: Also, Putze has a harsh negative connotation.